# Can you update or add a T-SQL query without checking if objects referenced within query exists

Tags: sql-server

I have to apply a series of T-SQL stored procedures to a SQL Server database.  One of the queries, although it is correct syntax-wise - gives an error that one of the objects in the query is missing.

So for example, the procedure has something like this (and yes - I declared the variable):

```sql
select @var1 = count(*) from MySchema.MyTable
```

On the client server, this fails because MySchema.MyTable doesn't exist although it has correct syntax.  In practice, MyTable is created earlier in the same procedure that this query is run.  But the creation of the table is via a string variable that creates a select-into query that creates the table.  So the compiler presumably can't tell that once it executes the string variable, that the table will exist.  But on my server, it doesn't seem to matter.

On our own servers, it doesn't fail when I update it.  It doesn't check for the presence of the object but will update it as long as the syntax is okay.

Is there some obscure SQLServer setting or SSMS setting that stops the compiler from checking if the object is there but still checks the syntax?

I should point out that I know how to check for the presence of a table before I query it but I didn't write these queries and as they worked on my server, there must be some reason that SQL didn't question it.

Comment: Take the time to post an [mre] here.

Comment: It's called Deferred Name Resolution and it cannot be disabled. When you say it fails on the client, *when* precisely do you see a problem? Is it possible that the "create a table via a dynamic query" is only conditionally executed?

Comment: What exactly does "the same procedure" mean? Do you mean "stored procedure"? Or do you mean a script (or set of scripts) you are using to "apply a series of T-SQL stored procedures".